# disk drive errors during startup - What do they mean?

Tags: hard-drive, error-handling

I get some of this error during startup:

```
[    6.453064] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[    6.453083] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:00:80:5f:77/00:00:72:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[    6.453083]          res 40/00:0c:90:fb:6a/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[    6.453127] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
```

after that it says: `errors were found while checking the disk drive for /home/` and I can choose between skip, ignore and manual mounting. If I choose to ignore the errors, it boots and works perfectly and as I see fast.

SMART Data & self-test about the hdd:

[image]

I don't really know much about that, so does the ata cable make the errors or the hdd? Do you think it will slow down my system?

At least, can I ignore it automatically?

Thanks, adamkrisz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've just run `fsck /dev/sdb7` and it's fixed